How to use || as a function name and apply it to calculate the equivalent resistance of parallel resistors as we typically write?
The equivalent resistance $ R_{eq}$ of $n$ resistors in parallel can be calculated from this: 

Would it be possible to define a function to calculate the equivalent resistance of resistors with the function name ||? I would like to apply it like this: R1 || R2, R1 || R2 || R3, or any number of parameters, and it would return the equivalent resistance. 
I know how to write a standard function to calculate the equivalent resistance of parallel resistors. However, what I am seeking here is the ability to use a function named || and apply it in the manner of R1 || R2, R1 || R2 || R3, as we typically write.  
Here are typical functions for calculating equivalent parallel resistance.

Be aware that you will have to tell the operator precedence (for example should : R1+R2 || R3 be interpeted as (R1+R2) || R3 or R1+(R2 || R3) ? ), unless you use all the necessary parenthesis systematically.

@andre314 Users should add parenthesis to make it behave as they want. Thanks for clarification.

|| already has a definition as the built-in function Or.

@ChrisK That's sad. Can we still use it somehow, given that the two functions operate on different types? One is for logical boolean operations, and the other is not. Alternatively, is there any similar symbol we can use that isn't a built-in function?

This answer has a nice list of potential candidates

@LukasLang Some of them look okay, like arrows in both directions, but I would prefer something that is easy to type since I use it a lot.

If you really insist on using ||, you can do this by creating an auxilliary function: eval[e_] := e /. Or -> (1/Total[1/{##}] &); R1 || R2 || R3 // eval Alternatively, you could put this into $Post if you really do not expect to use the logical Or for its regular purposes.

@Domen Nice trick. I realized that "//" is even more convenient as I don't need to type SHIFT like "||".
However, "//" is also a built-in function for Postfix.
If I want to use the tip you mentioned, is this correct?
eval[e_] := e /. Postfix -> (1/Total[1/{##}] &); R1 || R2 || R3 // eval

I think // will be more difficult to alter. What about using | (Alternatives)? $Post = Function[e, e /. Alternatives -> (1/Total[1/{##}] &)]; Example. But again, this hacks can bite you after some time ...

@Domen Would there be a way to check because // as Postfix is followed by a function while resistance is just a variable?
One more reason that I want to use // is that I can capture the code directly and send it to someone; they'll understand what // means without any explanation.

It won't work with || for reasons described in the comments. However, you can use a unicode character ∥ or U+2225 which Mathematica just so happens to call \[DoubleVerticalBar]. Then you can define some infix notation for it:
Remove["Global`*"];
Needs["Notation`"];
RParallel[x__] := 1/(Total[1/{x}])
AddInputAlias["4" -> ParsedBoxWrapper["∥"]];
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["∥"], RParallel];

a ∥ b ∥ c ∥ d

(* 1/(1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 1/d) *)


Thanks. It's a very nice solution.
I just realized that using // (Postfix) is even more convenient to type, so I'm trying to make that work as well while keeping the built-in function.

Would there be a way to shorten the typing of \[DoubleVerticalBar] as I use it a lot?

@internet no, however, you can just type \[Dou and find it in the autocomplete from the notebook interface, or copy and paste the symbol.

@internet, see InputAliases, e.g. CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {InputAliases, "xx"}] = "\[DoubleVerticalBar]"
